# Calculate and add hash to a file in python

Tags: python, hash, checksum

a way of checking if a file has been modified, is calculating and storing a hash (or checksum) for the file. Then at any point the hash can be re-calculated and compared against the stored value.

I'm wondering if there is a way to store the hash of a file in the file itself? I'm thinking text files.

The algorithm to calculate the hash should be iterative and consider that the hash will be added to the file the hash is being calculated for... makes sense? Anything available?

Thanks!

edit:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3851/can-a-file-contain-its-md5sum-inside-it

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense - store the checksum *separately* from the file.

Comment: If you store the hash in the file the hash of the file will change.

Comment: no sense at all, if you transfer checksum with file, anyone can modifiy now even your checksum

Comment: How is this much different than [HMAC](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20129/how-and-when-do-i-use-hmac/20301). You hash your message with your private key. Then, when you look at that message later, you try hashing it again and if the hashes don't much, you know someone changed something. It's a matter of Integrity, not Confidentiality. Meaning: I think it's a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @KlausD. sound logic, but NTFS has more magic...

Comment: The answer from @dwanderson kind of does the job. I was thinking that, theoretically, a string X should exist such that after added at a text file would result in this file having a hash equals to X, like a transcendental equation. I don't think jonrsharpe, Klaus D and Sergius understood that part. As for where to store it and why to store it in the file itself, well, that's up to who's using and an efficient way of doing it is another history. This is more of a theoretical question, so, as for practicalities, screw practicalities =)

Comment: @Raf you mean like `hash(text + X) = X`? I guess it depends on your hash function. I was going to say that'd be absurdly impractical (but you've already said screw practicalities :), but then I realized it's only impractical for "large" hashes, because worst-case you need to exhaust the hash space every time you change the file, and if you've got SHA256 or something, well, good luck with that. BUT, with a smaller search space (parity bits and error-correcting-codes come to mind but I can't think of an explanation yet), that should be reasonable.

Comment: ... one quick example, though it adds a slight wrinkle because of the nature of my "`hash function`" ie `xor`. If you `xor` all the bytes in a file together into `value`, then store the last byte as `value ^ 0xff`. Now, when you read back in the file to check for changes, you check that the `xor` of all the bytes (including your final "magic" byte) is equal to `0xff`. If it's not, something definitely changed (if it is, well, maybe the change got lucky - but that's what you get for only using 8 bits of check). Also, you can change `0xff` to any desired value (actually 0x00 makes more sense...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from Crypto.Hash import HMAC
secret_key = "Don't tell anyone"
h = HMAC.new(secret_key)
text = "whatever you want in the file"
## or: text = open("your_file_without_hash_yet").read()
h.update(text)
with open("file_with_hash") as fh:
    fh.write(text)
    fh.write(h.hexdigest())
```

Now, as some people tried to point out, though they seemed confused - you need to remember that this file has the hash on the end of it and that the hash is itself not part of what gets hashed. So when you want to **check** the file, you would do something along the lines of:

```
end_len = len(h.hex_digest())
all_text = open("file_with_hash").read()
text, expected_hmac = all_text[:end_len], all_text[end_len:]
h = HMAC.new(secret_key)
h.update(text)
if h.hexdigest() != expected_hmac:
    raise "Somebody messed with your file!"
```

It should be clear though that this *alone* doesn't ensure your file hasn't been changed; the typical use case is to encrypt your file, but take the hash of the plaintext. That way, if someone changes the hash (at the end of the file) or tries changing any of the characters in the message (the encrypted portion), things will mismatch and you will know something was changed.

A malicious actor won't be able to change the file AND fix the hash to match because they would need to change some data, and then rehash everything **with your private key**. So long as no one knows your private key, they won't know how to recreate the correct hash.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. You can do it if you adopt a proper convention for hashing and verifying the integrity of the files. Suppose you have this file, namely, `main.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
print "hello world"
```

Now, you could append an [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash to the python file as a comment:

```
(printf '#'; cat main.py | sha1sum) >> main.py
```

Updated `main.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
print "hello world"
#30e3b19d4815ff5b5eca3a754d438dceab9e8814  -
```

Hence, to verify if the file was modified you can do this in Bash:

```
if [ "$(printf '#';head -n-1 main.py | sha1sum)" == "$(tail -n1 main.py)" ]
then
    echo "Unmodified"
else 
    echo "Modified"
fi
```

Of course, someone could try to fool you by changing the hash string manually. In order to stop these bad guys, you can improve the system by tempering the file with a **secret string** before adding the hash to the last line.

### Improved version

Add the hash in the last line including your secret string:

```
(printf '#';cat main.py;echo 'MyUltraSecretTemperString12345') | sha1sum >> main.py
```

For checking if the file was modified:

```
if [ "$(printf '#';(head -n-1 main.py; echo 'MyUltraSecretTemperString12345') | sha1sum)" == "$(tail -n1 main.py)" ]
then
    echo "Unmodified"
else 
    echo "Modified"
fi
```

Using this improved version, the bad guys only can fool you if they find your ultra secret key first.

**EDIT:** This is a rough implementation of the [keyed-hash message authentication code (HMAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).

Comment: Is there a difference between your suggestion and just using an HMAC?

Comment: @dwanderson, In fact I didn't know about the HMAC approach. It appears my answer handle the same approach in a shell way. But it is good to know there is an more sophisticated way to handle that task.

Comment: Impressive that you came up with the industry standard in a few minutes off the top of your head! Solid work!

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't came from the top off my head =(. I just remembered the way JSON web tokens are signed and reproduced the general idea.

Comment: Ah makes sense. Yeah, this is a perfectly normal way to sign a file, I'm not sure why so many original commenters were confused as to why someone would want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well although it looks like a strange idea, it could be an application of a little used but very powerful property of windows NTFS file system: the [File Streams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It allows to add many *streams* to a file without changing the content of the default stream. For example:

```
echo foo > foo.text
echo bar > foo.text:alt
type foo.text
=>   foo
more < foo.text:alt
=>   bar
```

But when listing the directory, you can only see one single file: `foo.txt`

So in your use case, you could write the hash of main stream in stream named `hash`, and later compare the content of the `hash` stream with the hash of the main stream.

Just a remark: for a reason I do not know, `type foo.text:alt` generates the following error:

> "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

that's why my example uses `more <` as recommended in the [Using streams page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN

So assuming you have a `myhash` function that gives the hash for a file (you can easily build one by using the `hashlib` module):

```
def myhash(filename):
    # compute the hash of the file
    ...
    return hash_string
```

You can do:

```
def store_hash(filename):
    hash_string = myhash(filename)
    with open(filename + ":hash") as fd:
        fd.write(hash_string)

def compare_hash(filename):
        hash_string = myhash(filename)
        with open(filename + ":hash") as fd:
            orig = fd.read()
        return (hash_string == orig)
```

Comment: What in the world has this to do with helping the OP implement this in Python?

Comment: @dwanderson: you are right. I first answered with general information. I've now updated my post with some Python code.

Comment: The OP specifically asked to store the hash in the file itself, which is a valid and reasonable request, despite the comments on the question; your solution does not account for that AND you don't help provide the hash function, which seems like a large portion of the original question. The OP wants to know "can I store the hash after the file" (you don't address that) and "the hash should be iterative" implies "what hash do i use, or how?" (you assume they already have a hash function).

Comment: @dwanderson: I have explained that the alternate streams are still contained in the file. When you copy the file with `copy src dest`, you copy **all the streams**. And OP did not ask to store the hash **after** the file but **in** the file. And the standard module `hashlib` offers enough hashes.

Comment: Fair point aboutt he streams - I got confused by the Windows stuff so I didn't follow as well. I guess I would've mentioned `hashlib` in the answer then, as the OP doesn't seem to be aware and is asking for advice on such.

Comment: @dwanderson: That's the reason why my initial answer was only about the NTFS streams ;-) - Anyway it is now better with your remarks...